# Reducing the size of the screen

Tags: broken-screen

I have a LG G Pad 8.3 which its digitizer is broken and touch of the half of the screen is unresponsive, is it possible to reduce the resolution just from top side of the screen. kind of like cropping.

Answer (score -1):

I have similar problem with my Nexus7. Try [NOMone Resolution Changer](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nomone.resolution_changer). It allows you to choose diferent aspect ratio for screen. Is it possible to find combination to suit your needs:

> Two Android shell commands control screen resolution and density (dots per inch):
>
> - am display-size
> - am display-density
>
> For Android 4.3 and higher, these two commands were moved from am to wm. Now they are:
>
> - wm size
> - wm density
>
> This application nicely wraps these two commands so you can try different settings quickly and easily. It doesn't implement these functions, it merely uses them. So, if they don't behave well on your device then there is nothing we can do about it, please don't rate us down. We are just trying to make things easier.

Comment: Please provide a link, with maybe some directions, so others can follow along. And also to make it a complete answer

Comment: @RyanConrad I think it does perfectly answer the question (from what I understand – I've not tried it). Ahem, well, after my edit at least – but it was rassha providing the pointer :)